# Google Sheet Coinmarketcap requesting 1 single importxml instead of 1 request for each coin

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am developing a sheet in google sheet that pulls data from coinmarketcap with a script i've been trying to write.

I am a f. noob @ coding.

I use the function importxml (i need to refresh the latest price for each coin, like 100 coins) in this script:

```
function CryptoRefresher() {

        var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
        var queryString = Math.random();
        var link1 = "C";
        var xpath = "D";
        var destination = "E";
        var Direction=SpreadsheetApp.Direction;
        var NumeroRighe =spreadsheet.getRange("B"+(spreadsheet.getLastRow()+1)).getNextDataCell(Direction.UP).getRow();

        for (var i = 2; i <= NumeroRighe; i++) {
    var cellFunction1 = '=IMPORTXML("' + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(link1+i).getValue() + '?' + queryString + '", "'+ SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(xpath+i).getValue() + '")';
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(destination+i).setValue(cellFunction1);
    }
          };


        Example Data:

        Cell B2 = "bitcoin"
        cell C2 = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/Bitcoin"
        Cell D2 = "//div[@class='priceValue___11gHJ']"
        Cell E2 = is the destination and will receive the bitcoin price
```

The problem is that it's really slow because it calls 1 coin per time.

Question: Is there a way to send ALL THE COINS REQUESTS in 1 single importxml call?

Like I'd like to collect all the coin names in column C (1 cell of column C has 1 different and unique Coin Name) to collect all the coin names that i am watching and ask for 1 single call to speed up the process?

(Is there a way to create an array, a list of the coin names and do 1 single call to coinmarketcap?)

I really can't figure that out and i hope what i'm asking is clear!

Thank you!
Alessandro

Answer (score 0):

Given the structure of the webpage, it is currently not possible to have a single `IMPORTXML` call to pull multiple arbitrary currencies from the CoinMarketCap site.

However, they have a convenient API that can do that exactly, please see references below:

[CoinMarketCap API / Cryptocurrency](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#tag/cryptocurrency)

And this should get you started in pulling information from the API:

[Pulling Currency Data to Google Sheets](https://mixedanalytics.com/knowledge-base/import-coinmarketcap-data-to-google-sheets/#num4)

Comment: Thank you, gonna try to solve with what you suggested me!

Comment: If my answer has helped you solve your problem, please click on the check mark beside the answer to accept it. This way, more people having the same problem will be able to see the question and the solution. Please let me know if there are issues a well. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a dedicated service to retrieve the data, for instance this request will give you the data you need without any parsing or signing up to 3rd party services

`=IMPORTDATA("https://cryptoprices.cc/BTC")`

Trying to parse a complex web page under active development is just prone to fail at some point.

As alternative, go straight to the source, by signing up to the CoinMarketCap api to get more up to date data. (Already mentioned above) You can sign up for the free tier API (333 req/day) at https://pro.coinmarketcap.com/signup/

Answer (score 0):

Wow! Сryptoprices.cc it’s a great service.
[But some cryptocurrencies don’t read clearly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNJpC.png)

[If you change the formula, add / the price is updated and it is correct.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IAB4.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).